# How can i use shared memory on a fork with shmget?

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory

I'm study the shared memory on C but i don't understand how to use the share memory when i want to change the value on the child process. I worte this simple code but it doesn't work as i expexted, did i miss something?

**CODE:**

```
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int create_shared_memory(){
    return shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
}
int get_shared_memory(int key){
    return shmget(key,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
}
int* attachd_shared_memory(int key){
    return shmat(key,NULL,0);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("\nSono il PID: %d di PID: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    int sh_id = create_shared_memory();
    int *result = attachd_shared_memory(sh_id);
    
    int x = 5;
    result = &x;
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d\n",*result,x);
    *result = 9;
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d\n",*result,x);
    if (!fork())
    {
        int sh2_id = get_shared_memory(sh_id);
        int* result2 = attachd_shared_memory(sh2_id);
        int y = 4;
        result2 = &y;
        printf("Sono il PID: %d di PID: %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
        printf("ID: %d %d\n",sh_id,sh2_id);
        printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d\n",*result2,x);
        exit(0);
    }
  
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         {
            printf("\nHo finito di aspettare:%d  sono il padre: %d\n",wait(NULL),getppid());
         }
           shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d \n",*result,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank for the advice, i have to read better the basic of c but this satisfy my request.
**SOLUTION:**

```
int create_shared_memory(){
    return shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
}
int get_shared_memory(int key){
    return shmget(key,sizeof(int),0644);
}
int* attachd_shared_memory(int key){
    return shmat(key,NULL,0);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("\nSono il PID: %d di PID: %d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    int sh_id = create_shared_memory();
    int *result = attachd_shared_memory(sh_id);
    
    int x = 5;
    *result = x;
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d\n",*result,x);
    *result = 9;
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d\n",*result,x);
    if (!fork())
    {
       *result = 4;
        printf("Sono il PID: %d di PID: %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
       
        exit(0);
    }
  
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         {
            printf("\nHo finito di aspettare:%d  sono il padre: %d\n",wait(NULL),getppid());
         }
           shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("Puntatore: %i Numero(x): %d \n",*result,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *it doesn't want* - doesn't work you mean? Doesn't work how?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `attachd_shared_memory()` in the child. Shared memory is automatically inherited by the child.

Comment: now it's completed, sorry i forgot somethings

Comment: ok but, if i want to modify the value?? In the program start as 9, i want to modify it to 4 and i want that the modified value will be stored in a variable that the parent print

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the pointer to the shared memory when you do

```
result = &x;
```

Now `result` points to the private memory of `x` instead of the shared memory segment.

The child has the same problem when it does

```
result = &y;
```

You can't turn private memory into shared memory by assigning its address to `result`. So don't do those assignments.

Just use `*result` as the shared memory. Anything you assign to that in one process will be visible in the other.

So use

```
*result = x;
```

to store the value of `x` in the shared memory, and

```
y = *result;
```

to retrieve it.

Comment: I have to use `result` to store a data, like this : result = 4; ?? Sorry but i have no experience in C so i have difficulties in pointers to.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Although if you have no experience, you really need to learn the basics before moving to an advanced concept like shared memory.

Comment: in the child i have to `get_shared_memory` ??

Comment: No, because it inherits the shared memory from the parent automatically.

Comment: if i don't use the shared memory, the variable in the father will not change cause the child will operate in a copy if it, right?

Comment: No. Shared memory is not copied, it stays shared. So you attach the shared memory in the parent, then fork the child, and they both share it.